# Mongoid dependent :destroy vs :delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

When using Mongoid referenced reletions what's the diffrence between dependent detroy and dependent delete since in the docs it tells:

```
:delete: Delete the child documents.
:destroy: Destroy the child documents.
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Mongoid (and also ActiveRecord I believe), `delete` just removes the object from the database.  `destroy` will delete the object and run all of the appropriate callbacks that the model has defined.  So if you have a `before_destroy` callback on a model and you `delete` an instance of that model, the `before_destroy` callback will not be called.

So `dependent: :destroy` runs the model's callbacks when deleting and `dependent: :delete` does not.

Comment: so if I don't have any callback they are the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, I would probably consider using `destroy`.  If you ever do add a callback, you'll need to remember to change it from `delete` to `destroy` unless you don't want the callback to actually run.

Comment: No they are not the same thing even if you don't have callbacks. Because `destroy` is dependent on callbacks, it has to load the related document in order to execute the callbacks, and the do the DELETE query. `delete` just makes a DELETE query.
Then, destroy is "safer", but delete is "faster"

Answer (score 4):

- `destroy` runs model callbacks and then makes a REMOVE query to the DB.
- `delete` just makes a REMOVE query to the DB.

The names are taken from `ActiveRecord`, that's why they don't match mongo very well.

You could see `delete` as an optimization over `destroy`. When you use `destroy`, you make sure that `before_destroy` callbacks are executed, so proper cleanup is done. In the other hand, if you do something like `Model.destroy_all`, it has to load ALL elements, and then make a REMOVE query for each of them, whether `Model.delete_all` makes just one query.